# Proving law of reflection using Huygens principle

Tags: waves, reflection, interference, superposition

So I was reading the proof of law of reflection using Huygens principle but as I am new on this website so I can't attach a picture,so I will try to explain by writing only.

The problem I face is that I believe Huygens principle is used when all the particles of wavefront that is ,the particles which oscillate in same phase can act as source of secondary wavelets.In my book they have selected the reflecting surface as source of secondary wavelets but the incident wavefront is inclined at an angle,so how can I assume reflecting surface to be source of secondary wavelets?

Moreover the particles used as source of secondary wavelets arise at different times,I mean the particles of initial wavefront which are closer to the reflecting surface start producing secondary wavelets as soon as they touch the mirror while the particle of wavefront farthest from the mirror just touches the mirror and becomes the point of secondary wavelets instead being the source of wavelets like other particles on wavefront,is this true?

Comment: Huygen's principle is pure wave optics that has nothing to do with particles. The way to get from there to ray optics (sometimes also identified as particle optics) is trough the eikonal approximation which one can then specialize to the case of plane waves corresponding to flat wavefronts and straight rays. Is that the kind of thing you are looking for? As a physical picture each point on a wavefront is the starting point of a new circular wave with the same phase as the original.

Comment: I ll tell you what's mentioned in the book.For proving law of reflection we  suppose that a parallel beam of light is incident upon a reflecting plane surface CD.The wavefronts of the incident wave will be planes perpendicular to the direction of incidence.After reflection,the light returns in the same medium.Consider a particular wavefront AB of the incident light wave at t=0.We shall construct the position of wavefront at time t.

Comment: To apply hugens construction we use the reflecting surface CD for the source of secondary wavelets.As the various points of CD are reached by wavefront AB,they become source of secondary wavelets.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it appears to have been abandoned by its author and it has no answers.

Comment: @sammygerbil: whoa now, an abandoned question is ***not*** a reason to close a question; there are plenty of examples on MSE about this, if you bothered to even look.

Comment: @KyleKanos I disagree. Old questions which have no answers are not useful to anyone. They only waste time because the "related" list includes questions which have no answers. This is probably a duplicate of some other question. [This MSE answer by Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) does in fact say that old questions with no answer will be automatically deleted under certain circumstances. This answer has 286 votes. The question itself, asking for such deletions, has 214 votes.

Comment: @sammygerbil: Questions aren't meant just for the OP, but also for those with the same question later ([see Joel Spolsky's talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LpGA2fmAHvM)). Just because it isn't answered now doesn't mean you should *rob* the future readers of the chance for an answer (or a future answerer the chance to answer it) simply because you feel the author has abandoned it (even though their last visit was 8 days ago).

Comment: @sammygerbil: see also [a mod's comment on this particular issue](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36726495#36726495)

Comment: @KyleKanos A moderator's opinion in the chat room is not a decision by the community. ... If somebody wants to answer this question I have no objections, but if somebody comes along later looking for an answer to this question he/she is not going to adopt the question, he/she is going to post a new question; this qn will become a duplicate. So if this qn were deleted it would not rob anyone from getting or posting an answer. ... Joel Spolsky's talk is 55 minutes long, I do not intend to spend 55 minutes looking for support for your opinion.

Comment: @KyleKanos The OP's last visit to the site may have been 8 days ago, but his last edit to the question was December 2015.

Comment: @sammygerbil You can start a meta post about this and wait for people to give their opinions.

Comment: @sammygerbil you are objecting to someone answering this question by voting to close it... And Joel's talk is well worth the hour; you might actually learn something

Comment: @KyleKanos I am not objecting to anyone posting an answer. I am pointing out that nobody has shown any interest in the question for 15 months - until I suggested that it be deleted, then it's like "Save the Panda!"

Comment: @sammygerbil There's no community decision to be made here - that a question is old and hasn't accrued any interest is not a reason to close it. Questions are to be closed because they are *unclear*, *too broad*, *off-topic*, or otherwise run afoul of established site policy. "This question is old" is not a violation of any policy and therefore not a reason to close it. If the automatic system does not delete it then it's considered fine to stay on the site forever, regardless of attention. I would have no qualms about unilaterally reopening any question closed for such a spurious reason.